# Checkbox in MVC 5 ASP.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I made a "Availability" option in my database, this is set as a "bit". When I made a controller on my generated model, it came out as a dropdownlist with 2 values: true and false. I don't want this to be a dropdown list but a checkbox. I've googled all around and couldnt find an easy fix for this. Any of you have an idea how to do this? My code looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Beschikbaar, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Beschikbaar)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Beschikbaar, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please include the declaration and any attributes for `Beschikbaar`.

Comment: write the html and give the name as the property name

Comment: It will only generate a dropdownlist if your property is nullable (`bool?`) and then it will generate 3 options (not 2 as you claim) unless you have created an `EditorTemplate` for `bool`. But in any case you can use `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Beschikbaar)` if it really is `bool`

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Beschikbaar, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
           @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Beschikbaar)
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Beschikbaar, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Beschikbaar" value="true" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Beschikbaarfield is required."/>
```

in place of the line

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Beschikbaar)
```

Comment: No, use the html helper. `@Html.CheckBoxFor(x = x.Beschikbaar)`

Comment: what's wrong with using this. Can you explain? If you view source of what you have written, then you will see something like this only what i have stated. also your server won't spend it's resources to compile your C# code to HTML. This is the best practice we follow. Use C# only for business logic that can't be done in JS. Use HTML and JS for everything else.

Comment: _Whats wrong with it_ It does not even have a `value` attribute and cannot even bind to a `bool` property. Its `checked` attribute is not set based on the value of the model. It does not contain the `data-val-` attributes necessary for client side validation, If `ModelState` is invalid and the view is returned, the data the user entered is lost, etc etc. I strongly suggest you compare the html generated by `Hml.CheckBoxFor()` with yours to see all the differences. The `HtmlHelpers` will always generate the correct html needed to 2-way model binding and client/server side validation.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - couldn't have said it better myself :)

Comment: @It'satrap - The helpers are there for a reason.  use them.  Like many language features, they help you from shooting yourself in the foot and making common mistakes.  My guess is that as much as 20% of the MVC questions on StackOverflow would not happen if people used the helpers correctly.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I did it and found out that you were right. It won't bind to property without the value attribute.